# Get elements in jQuery where "x" attribute = "y"

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the attribute of an element, depending on another attribute?

For example, I have 2 `<a>` elements. They both have the class `myClass`. One of the elements has `rel="1"` and the other has `rel="2"`. I wish to only change the `z-index` on the one which has `rel=1`. How do I do this?

I've tried:

```
$(".myClass[rel='1']").css("z-index", 10);
```

But it doesn't work. Cheers.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WFznU/ (it might not be obvious that the `z-index` changed)

Comment: Problem is if you try and return the value of `z-index` after setting it it says auto, thus it must not have saved correctly.

Comment: Better example: http://jsfiddle.net/WFznU/5/ So the problem must be somewhere else... or **why** do you think it does not work?

Comment: Is the element positioned somehow?  What browser are you using?  Maybe it just says "auto" if setting the z-index value doesn't make sense (like for an inline element or a statically-positioned element).

Comment: try $(".myClass[rel='1']").css('display', 'none'); and see if it disappears. Then you will know if it is your selector, or positioning.

Comment: @jruddell, I've had a go at changing the display and this works, so it must be a different issue! To be honest I didn't know that was valid syntax, i was just giving an example of how i'd like it to work. good old jquery!

Comment: now then, how do i mark this as answered??

Comment: I added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".myClass[rel='1']").css('display', 'none');
```

and see if it disappears. Then you will know if it is your selector, or positioning.

Answer (score 0):

As `z-index` contains a hyphen you have to reference it in camel case:

```
$(".myClass[rel='1']").css("zIndex", 10);
```

Comment: That is not true, if you set the the style via `css(attr, value)`, you can use the "normal" CSS names for the attributes. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/WFznU/1/